# FFMPEG MXF -> MP4 - Cannot get proper audio on output file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, mxf

I am software developer working on a project that requires my video files to be an mp4 format, as this is what most vendors support. I am trying to use ffmpeg, to rewrap the MXF file, into an mp4.

Here is the probe.

[image]

Attempting a direct

```
ffmpeg -i c:\Users\206420055\Downloads\MAAAAAHVIY.mxf -c:v copy -c:a copy test.mp4
```

the video works, but the audio appears to be squished into the first few seconds of the video. As well as seeking does not work properly on the video.

Trying to use `libmp3lame` as the audio codec, it complains about

> [libmp3lame @ 0000000002d08900] Queue input is backward in time [mp4 @
>   0000000003887fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous:
>   1565 375, current: 1564346; changing to 1565376. This may result in
>   incorrect timesta mps in the output file.

I have tried a variety of adding `-af aresample=async=1000` (and other hertz values), which succeeds in removing the warnings, but does not succeed in fixing the video.

Does anyone have any ideas what else I am missing? I have tried to map the individual streams to the output as well, with no luck.

---

Full console when running 
`ffmpeg.exe -i c:\Users\206420055\Downloads\MAAAAAHVIY.mxf  -c:v copy -c:a copy -report testing.mp4`

```
c:\dev\ffmpeg-20161230-6993bb4-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg.exe -i c:\Users\206420055
\Downloads\MAAAAAHVIY.mxf  -c:v copy -c:a copy -report testing.mp4
ffmpeg started on 2017-01-09 at 12:10:03
Report written to "ffmpeg-20170109-121003.log"
ffmpeg version N-82966-g6993bb4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx -
-enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei
0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-li
bbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --en
able-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-li
bopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --e
nable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable
-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --e
nable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavcodec     57. 70.100 / 57. 70.100
  libavformat    57. 61.100 / 57. 61.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 68.100 /  6. 68.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mxf, from 'c:\Users\206420055\Downloads\MAAAAAHVIY.mxf':
  Metadata:
    application_platform: Omneon Media Api (mqx)
    uid             : 7889285c-97b8-161e-b2af-00d02813303e
    generation_uid  : 8289285c-97b8-161e-8c77-00d02813303e
    company_name    : Omneon Inc.
    product_name    : Omneon Media Subsystem
    modification_date: 2016-12-02T13:58:10.000000Z
    product_version : Omneon SB Release 7.9.0.0.62 (tags/7.9.x.0/7.9.0.0.11),ex=
{0,-1},rng={0,-1,8},exPre
    product_uid     : 00000000-0000-1000-8000-050e0b010602
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D231301066E8E44035197B8161E898
C00D02813303E
    timecode        : 08:58:00;04
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1
DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D231300E3D05291285C97B8161EA0A40
0D02813303E
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D231300E3D05291285C97B8161EA0A40
0D02813303E
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D231300E3D05291285C97B8161EA0A40
0D02813303E
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D231300E3D05291285C97B8161EA0A40
0D02813303E
    Stream #0:4: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D231300E3D05291285C97B8161EA0A40
0D02813303E
Output #0, mp4, to 'testing.mp4':
  Metadata:
    application_platform: Omneon Media Api (mqx)
    uid             : 7889285c-97b8-161e-b2af-00d02813303e
    generation_uid  : 8289285c-97b8-161e-8c77-00d02813303e
    company_name    : Omneon Inc.
    product_name    : Omneon Media Subsystem
    modification_date: 2016-12-02T13:58:10.000000Z
    product_version : Omneon SB Release 7.9.0.0.62 (tags/7.9.x.0/7.9.0.0.11),ex=
{0,-1},rng={0,-1,8},exPre
    product_uid     : 00000000-0000-1000-8000-050e0b010602
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D231301066E8E44035197B8161E898
C00D02813303E
    timecode        : 08:58:00;04
    encoder         : Lavf57.61.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(progre
ssive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 29.97
 tbc
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D231300E3D05291285C97B8161EA0A40
0D02813303E
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt
p
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D231300E3D05291285C97B8161EA0A40
0D02813303E
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 8114 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   58047kB time=00:04:30.70 bitrate=1756.6kbits/
frame=15327 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=  120712kB time=00:08:31.37 bitrate=1933.7kbits/
frame=22191 fps=14794 q=-1.0 size=  179753kB time=00:12:20.40 bitrate=1988.8kbit
frame=27272 fps=13112 q=-1.0 size=  222031kB time=00:15:09.94 bitrate=1998.9kbit
frame=27306 fps=9819 q=-1.0 size=  222314kB time=00:15:11.07 bitrate=1998.9kbits
frame=29077 fps=8862 q=-1.0 size=  237699kB time=00:16:10.16 bitrate=2007.1kbits
frame=32305 fps=8419 q=-1.0 size=  265789kB time=00:17:57.87 bitrate=2020.0kbits
frame=32378 fps=7453 q=-1.0 size=  266393kB time=00:18:00.31 bitrate=2020.1kbits
frame=34179 fps=7056 q=-1.0 size=  282049kB time=00:19:00.40 bitrate=2026.1kbits
frame=37305 fps=6974 q=-1.0 size=  308619kB time=00:20:44.71 bitrate=2031.2kbits
frame=39711 fps=6666 q=-1.0 size=  328751kB time=00:22:04.99 bitrate=2032.6kbits
frame=39966 fps=6187 q=-1.0 size=  330953kB time=00:22:13.49 bitrate=2033.1kbits
frame=42056 fps=6043 q=-1.0 size=  348347kB time=00:23:23.23 bitrate=2033.6kbits
frame=44924 fps=6012 q=-1.0 size=  373270kB time=00:24:58.93 bitrate=2040.0kbits
frame=46764 fps=5841 q=-1.0 size=  389255kB time=00:26:00.32 bitrate=2043.7kbits
frame=46917 fps=5516 q=-1.0 size=  390614kB time=00:26:05.43 bitrate=2044.1kbits
frame=46918 fps=3183 q=-1.0 size=  390616kB time=00:26:05.46 bitrate=2044.1kbits
frame=50173 fps=3292 q=-1.0 size=  418106kB time=00:27:54.07 bitrate=2046.0kbits
frame=53009 fps=3366 q=-1.0 size=  441437kB time=00:29:28.70 bitrate=2044.6kbits
frame=53204 fps=3258 q=-1.0 size=  443135kB time=00:29:35.20 bitrate=2044.9kbits
frame=56009 fps=3328 q=-1.0 size=  467497kB time=00:31:08.80 bitrate=2049.3kbits
frame=60122 fps=3469 q=-1.0 size=  500061kB time=00:33:26.03 bitrate=2042.1kbits
frame=63046 fps=3529 q=-1.0 size=  525469kB time=00:35:03.60 bitrate=2046.3kbits
frame=63208 fps=3442 q=-1.0 size=  526867kB time=00:35:09.00 bitrate=2046.5kbits
frame=65119 fps=3449 q=-1.0 size=  543496kB time=00:36:12.77 bitrate=2049.1kbits
frame=69350 fps=3577 q=-1.0 size=  580081kB time=00:38:33.94 bitrate=2053.6kbits
frame=71850 fps=3603 q=-1.0 size=  601509kB time=00:39:57.36 bitrate=2055.4kbits
frame=71997 fps=3522 q=-1.0 size=  602790kB time=00:40:02.26 bitrate=2055.6kbits
frame=73545 fps=3512 q=-1.0 size=  615686kB time=00:40:53.91 bitrate=2055.4kbits
frame=78165 fps=3645 q=-1.0 size=  651742kB time=00:43:28.07 bitrate=2047.1kbits
frame=79980 fps=3624 q=-1.0 size=  667551kB time=00:44:28.63 bitrate=2049.2kbits
frame=80080 fps=3546 q=-1.0 size=  668364kB time=00:44:31.96 bitrate=2049.1kbits
frame=81095 fps=3510 q=-1.0 size=  677211kB time=00:45:05.83 bitrate=2050.3kbits
frame=81644 fps=3459 q=-1.0 size=  682016kB time=00:45:24.15 bitrate=2050.9kbits
frame=81896 fps=3386 q=-1.0 size=  684248kB time=00:45:32.56 bitrate=2051.3kbits
frame=81941 fps=3319 q=-1.0 size=  684629kB time=00:45:34.06 bitrate=2051.3kbits
frame=82384 fps=3270 q=-1.0 size=  688448kB time=00:45:48.84 bitrate=2051.7kbits
frame=83076 fps=3233 q=-1.0 size=  694402kB time=00:46:11.93 bitrate=2052.2kbits
frame=83263 fps=3172 q=-1.0 size=  696039kB time=00:46:18.17 bitrate=2052.4kbits
frame=86446 fps=3232 q=-1.0 size=  722836kB time=00:48:04.38 bitrate=2052.9kbits
frame=88403 fps=3242 q=-1.0 size=  739677kB time=00:49:09.68 bitrate=2054.3kbits
frame=89460 fps=3208 q=-1.0 size=  748572kB time=00:49:44.94 bitrate=2054.4kbits
frame=89620 fps=3153 q=-1.0 size=  749971kB time=00:49:50.28 bitrate=2054.6kbits
frame=90747 fps=3137 q=-1.0 size=  759297kB time=00:50:27.89 bitrate=2054.3kbits
frame=96196 fps=3269 q=-1.0 size=  805940kB time=00:53:29.70 bitrate=2057.0kbits
frame=98564 fps=3283 q=-1.0 size=  826519kB time=00:54:48.71 bitrate=2058.8kbits
frame=98650 fps=3230 q=-1.0 size=  827279kB time=00:54:51.58 bitrate=2058.9kbits
frame=98651 fps=3009 q=-1.0 size=  827285kB time=00:54:51.62 bitrate=2058.9kbits
frame=103872 fps=3120 q=-1.0 size=  872630kB time=00:57:45.82 bitrate=2062.6kbit
frame=108427 fps=3190 q=-1.0 size=  907403kB time=01:00:17.81 bitrate=2054.7kbit
frame=108503 fps=3132 q=-1.0 size=  908057kB time=01:00:20.35 bitrate=2054.7kbit
frame=108554 fps=3074 q=-1.0 size=  908463kB time=01:00:22.05 bitrate=2054.7kbit
frame=108712 fps=3019 q=-1.0 size=  909880kB time=01:00:27.32 bitrate=2054.9kbit
frame=108922 fps=2975 q=-1.0 size=  911695kB time=01:00:34.33 bitrate=2055.0kbit
frame=111604 fps=3006 q=-1.0 size=  934504kB time=01:02:03.82 bitrate=2055.8kbit
frame=114459 fps=3042 q=-1.0 size=  957610kB time=01:03:39.08 bitrate=2054.1kbit
frame=114904 fps=3001 q=-1.0 size=  961435kB time=01:03:53.93 bitrate=2054.3kbit
[mxf @ 00000000004b8060] next_ofs didn't change. not deriving packet timestamps
[mp4 @ 0000000003a07760] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is
deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timesta
mps properly
frame=115116 fps=2966 q=-1.0 Lsize=  968349kB time=01:04:01.00 bitrate=2065.3kbi
ts/s speed=  99x
video:906506kB audio:60016kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB m
uxing overhead: 0.188993%
```

Comment: Share the full console output of your copy command as text. Add `-report` if you wish.

Comment: @Mulvya added for your reference.

Comment: The audio output looks fine, is the first audio stream is the one you want. Which player did you test in?

Comment: I cant get sound to play in VLC, before or after the wrap. The file plays properly in a enterprise software we use .. Avid MediaCentral MAM... the file played fine inside the software, but when I pulled it locally it wont play with sound. I also tried with mpc-hc https://mpc-hc.org/  no luck. as for which stream, I cant tell because they all play nothing on either vlc or mpc-hc (video is fine)

Comment: File seeking is also an issue pre-wrap

Comment: Run `ffmpeg.exe -i c:\Users\206420055\Downloads\MAAAAAHVIY.mxf  -c copy -map 0:a:0 1.m4a`, `ffmpeg.exe -i c:\Users\206420055\Downloads\MAAAAAHVIY.mxf  -c copy -map 0:a:1 2.m4a`, `ffmpeg.exe -i c:\Users\206420055\Downloads\MAAAAAHVIY.mxf  -c copy -map 0:a:2 3.m4a` and `ffmpeg.exe -i c:\Users\206420055\Downloads\MAAAAAHVIY.mxf  -c copy -map 0:a:3 4.m4a` and check which files have working audio.

Comment: Thanks foryour advice, I have some morning meetings and will get back to you

Comment: number 1 has audio but it is not understandable, sounds at super speed. playing with `ffplay` plays proper audio... actually audio plays properly in mpc-hc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51519/discussion-between-busturdust-and-mulvya).